# Unable to sign in to network after moveing address but able to login into child sites

Tags: multisite, login

As above, I have a multi site installation with multiple child sites on, I am able to access all child sites but when I go to the network admin it asks me to login which I try to do but it just reloads, it gives no error message to say password incorrect or non user?

Answer (score 0):

Network admin is usually on the main (first) site in the network. If you have changed URL's for all individual sites, and if you have updated the wp_blogs and wp_site, you also need to change the main blog URL in the wp-config.php file for the DEFINE directive 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE'.